# percentage difference between two dataframe columns (only numeric)

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) and would like to subtract only numeric columns between the two dataframes `[(df2-df1)/df2]` and determine the percentage difference and create an output dataframe = df3 using R. Non-numeric columns will be retained as such.

`df1` and `df2` have the same structure and same column names.

df1:

```
colA colB colC   ...   colZ
mean   10   20      stringA
count  30   50      stringB
```

df2:

```
colA colB colC   ...  colZ
mean    5   25     stringA
count  60   50     stringB
```

df3:

```
colA  colB colC   ...   colZ
mean  -100   20      stringA
count   50    0      stringB
```

I tried this and didn't work:

```
 df2[,2:3] = (df2[,2:3] - df1[,2:3])/df2[,2:3]
```

could someone please help with this?

Comment: how are expecting -50 in colB in df3?

Comment: @7kemZmani oops will edit it - sorry!

Comment: @7kemZmani any idea how I could approach this? thank you.

Comment: Please choose one language.  R or Python.

Comment: @JohnZwinck R would be my preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can subset the numeric columns and then perform the operation

```
num_cols <- c("colB", "colC")
df3 <- (df2[num_cols] - df1[num_cols])/df2[num_cols] * 100
df3

#  colB colC
#1 -100   20
#2   50    0
```

To get other non numeric columns we can use `setdiff` and then `cbind`

```
cbind(df1[setdiff(names(df1), num_cols)], df3)

#   colA    colZ colB colC
#1  mean stringA -100   20
#2 count stringB   50    0
```